# LeviCivita tensor in Sympy tensor package

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to define a vectorial product with the sympy tensor module using the LeviCivita tensor. I did not find any way to do this. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

See [the SymPy docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.tensor_functions.LeviCivita). Usage examples are shown on that page.

Comment: I think this is not the correct way to implement it in the Tensor module. Tensor module must implement the LeviCivita (and it does) tensor in terms of the metric tensor.

Comment: More than this he LeviCivita symbole defined in this link is not  a tensor object and cannot be contracted with tensors.

Comment: @falematte Please provide a code example - it's not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: A contraction between this object and one or more tensors defined by means of the tensor module, e.g. LeviCivita(-i,-j,-k)*F(j)*G(k) where F and G are tensors (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/tensor.html).